# How to create windows docker image with VS test agents?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I couldn't find any windows image with test agents at microsoft's public docker repo. How can i create a windows docker image with Visual Studio Tests agents to run codedui/mstest?

On a general note `how to create a windows docker image with any gui based software pre-installed and pre-configured?`

*Note: This looks like a low research question, but i had to post it here  because docker+windows is relatively new thing and there aren't much information available on net as well.*

Comment: GUI is not supported in windows containers. But I would also like to know whether you can use container to host Test or TFS agents

Comment: Not TFS agents. I want to run codedui tests. The setup and configuration of VS test agents is a gui process though. So i guess its blocked till MS releases a command line setup of VS test agents. 

I have been running selenium UI tests perfectly on nix docker containers, so thought of giving a try for CodedUI as well.

Comment: @SarkarG did you get VS test agents to work in windows containers with Coded UI tests? Im interesting in the same scenario. Thank you

Comment: @kalasp Unfortunately no. It's impossible to run ui interactive tests on windows docker. So only way to run them is with multiple windows VMs. That wasn't much beneficial and costing us a lot, so for the greater good we decided to abandon our 1000+ ui tests and switched to testcafe instead. I have had great success with testcafe so far where i am currently running around 20+ UI (web) test in parallel on a single linux machine with multiple docker containers. Doesn't cost much on our corporate azure accounts. Earlier it was so much pain to setup CI-CT with codedui.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a VM template with the Microsoft Agent Software already installed on the machine. All the GUI setup does is modify an XML, so you could effectively:

1. Have a VM container with the AGENT already installed.
2. Stop the TestAgent service
3. Modify the Agent Configuration XML
4. Restart the TestAgent service

This could probably be achieved with a PowerShell script or a custom console application.

If you need more help, we could figure this out together. Please feel free to contact me on LinkedIn.

https://www.linkedin.com/in/david-o-neill-8a1aa498/